# How to use wordpress escape function for echo Google Adsense code?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, adsense

Hello I want to use escape function for echo Google Adsense code in WordPress.
Like Google Adsense code is saved in a variable.

```
$googleads = $redux_demo['google-ads']
```

Now i want to echo this variable with wwordpress escapr function.
I have already try these function.

```
esc_html($googleads);
esc_html__($googleads);
esc_attr($googleads);
esc_js($googleads);
wp_kses($googleads, $allowed_html);
wp_kses_post($googleads);
```

Nothing is working , 
Adsense code will be like this.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
    ata-ad-format="autorelaxed"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxx"
    data-ad-slot="xxxxx">
</ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

can you help me for this. 
Thanks

Answer (score -2):

What do you want to escape? It's a script and there is nothing to escape. If you are achieving the full script via `theme-option` then you don't have to escape its value though it's not a secure way. Many cases I have seen there is a just one or two option for `data-ad-client`
    `data-ad-slot` and if those are integer value then you can check them via `intval($option['data-ad-client'])`

[for more](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)

Comment: I already explain, All Gooogle Adsense code is save in a variable "$googleads" I want to echo is code with escape function, How i can echo this by using any escape function. Thanks

Comment: @MrShabir why do you want to escape Google adsense  code ? because of any plugin issue? try this  echo ($googleads);

Comment: This will not work in WordPress Rules, Because in WordPress When we need to echo any variable then we must need to use any escape function. That's why we must need to use escape function with echo.